# How to loop through list and get every href value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a for loop to loop through a list that has links and I am trying to get the href's value's and not being successful.
I can return the links by doing this..

> let me = $('#wizTabs li a');

but not able to still get the href.

I have tried me[i].attr("href") and I get an error about attr not being a function.
I also tried just $(this) and that didn't work

```js
let me = $('#wizTabs li');

for (i = 0; i < me.length; i++) {
  console.log(me[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="wizTabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#pnlCustomerAddress" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Customer Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlCustomerContacts" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlShipToAddress" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Ship To Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlImplementorAddress" data-toggle="tab">Company Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: me[i] is not a jQuery collection you cant use .attr() on it. its a DOM element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looping a jQuery collection with a for loop will give you the DOM elements of this collection and therefore you cannot use jQuery methods on them. you will have to wrap the DOM element in a $() in order to be able to use jQuery methods on it.

```js
let me = $('#wizTabs li a').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});

//Javascript solution
for (i = 0; i < me.length; i++) {
  console.log(me[i].getAttribute("href"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="wizTabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#pnlCustomerAddress" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Customer Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlCustomerContacts" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlShipToAddress" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Ship To Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlImplementorAddress" data-toggle="tab">Company Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: i actually did a comment on the question

Comment: @Stakvino yes, and making that part of the answer would be better. Not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: Well, considering you are changing `for (...)` with `.each()` and then still wrapping `this` in a jQuery object, it's actually less-efficient than the OP just doing `$(me[i]).attr("href")`. Both of which are less efficient than just `me[i].href`. So, some explanation on why your answer solves the problem is highly recommended.

Comment: `this` within iteration is actual JS DOM object, so you also could get `href` value just like `this.href` (without using jQyery)

Comment: @Andriy Which is what the OP had to begin with, with `me[i]`.

Comment: how comes ? my english is bad

Comment: @Stakvino `this` inside your `each()` iterator is exactly equivalent to `me[i]`. It's a DOM element. In order to get jQuery wrapper around the DOM element, you have to wrap `this` in `$()`, which you can also do with `me[i]`. So, `$(this)` is equivalent to `$(me[i])`. `.each()` vs `for (...)` is not the crux of the OP's issue.

Comment: true but looping with jQuery each method will return the collection for chaining and this is why i use it when working with jQuery and i just learned jQuery this month so i might be wrong somewhere

Comment: This solution works for using JQuery, but what about in plain javascript? @mhodges, me[i].href returns it as a link, but I just want the href text

Comment: @Stakvino, perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have included here 2 different ways to do it.

1. Using jQuery [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/), using `jQuery` to grab the array and loop through it, `each` does the same thing.
2. Using vanilla javascript on the array you already got.

**NOTE** they provide different values for href, one fully qualified and one not.  I did modify your `selector` to target the `anchor` and not the `list-item`

```js
let me = $('#wizTabs li a');
//using jquery map
$(me).map(function(idx, elem) {
  console.log($(elem).attr("href"));
});
//minimal changes to your code
for (i = 0; i < me.length; i++) {
  console.log(me[i].href);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="wizTabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#pnlCustomerAddress" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Customer Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlCustomerContacts" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlShipToAddress" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Ship To Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pnlImplementorAddress" data-toggle="tab">Company Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The me[i].href returns as a link but I just need the text as you shown by using map

Answer (score 1):

## [document.links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)

The most easiest HTMLCollections.

`document.links` gets you all links on a page

The following one liner uses:

- `document.links` to gather the links into a NodeList
- `Array.from()` to convert the NodeList into an array
- `map()` to get the value of each `[href]` attr/prop.

---

```js
var lnx = Array.from(document.links).map((A, i) => A.href);

console.log(lnx);
```

```css
a::after {content:' 'attr(href)}
```

```html
<a href="#/"></a><br>
<a href="https://google.com"></a><br>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.vom"></a><br>
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net"></a><br>
<a href="https://next.plnkr.co"></a><b>
<a href="https://cdnjs.com"></a><br>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links">document.links</a><br>
```